# Why does this spread operator output unexpected values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread

```js
const arr = [7, 8, 9];

const badArr  = [1, 2, arr];

const newArr = [1, 2, ...arr];

console.log('Bad array: ' + badArr);
console.log('Good array: ' + newArr);
```

I was expecting [1,2,[7,8,9]] for the badArr, instead I got the same return of [1,2,7,8,9]. Is this something newer in JS? (Completing an older course).

Comment: That's because you're using under the hood Array.prototype.toString() when concatenating it with the prefixed String portion text `'Bad array: ' +`. Try like: `console.log(badArr);` will give you `[1, 2, [7, 8, 9]]` Then try what you do: `console.log("foo: " + badArr);` will give you `"foo: 1, 2, 7, 8, 9"` and to confirm use `console.log(badArr.toString())` which will give you `"1, 2, 7, 8, 9"`

Comment: If you use `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`, you'll see what you  expect. (`console.dir(badArray)` to be clear.)

Comment: Or enter each array directly into console and see what it prints.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Log it as followed: `console.log('Bad array:', badArr);`

Answer (score 2):

The + operator between a String and an Array is a concatenation, your Array is [stringified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) and appended to your debug String when you log it.

Your variables contain the intended values anyway.

What can you do to avoid this:

```js
const arr = [7, 8, 9];

const badArr = [1, 2, arr];

console.log('Bad result: ' + badArr); // returns String
console.log('Good result: ', badArr); // returns String and Array
```